# Correlation among features

Tags: python, correlation

I have the following question in python:

I want to print the correlation <0.9 of multiple feature on just ONE feature (here: 'Volume'):
In this case, example refers to my dataframe

Code:

```
correlation=example.corr().abs()
correlation_lower=correlation('Volume')
my_feature=correlation_lower[correlatio_lower<0.9]
```

I then transformed my result into a DataFrame and named the colum Feature:

```
my_features=pd.DataFrame(my_feature)
my_feature['Feature']=my_feature.index
```

So I have now a dataFrame with my feature the the respective correlation on the variable 'Volume'.

Now I want to check on those features with correlation smaller 0.9 and check the correlation among them.
I tried it with a for loop, but this does not work:

```
for my_feature['Feature'] in example:
        print(example_corr())
```

In the end, I would like to have the names of those features, whose correlation is lower than 0.9 for volumes and do not correlate among each other.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand your question, you want the list of features which have the correlation value (with Volume) less than 0.9.

```
corrmat =  example.corr()
print(list(corrmat[(corrmat["Volume"]<0.9)]["Volume"].index.values))
```

EDIT:

After reading your comment, I think this may work for you:

```
corrmat=train_df.corr()
select_fet = set(list(corrmat[(corrmat["Volume"]<0.9)].index.values))
corrmat = corrmat[(corrmat["Volume"]<0.9)].transpose()
for i in corrmat:
    select_fet = select_fet.intersection(set(corrmat[(corrmat[i]<0.9)].index.values))
print(select_fet)
```

Comment: Hi, I have already done that. What I want to do now is take the features with correlation less than 0.9, check the correlation among those features and kick the features out that correlate. For example: The features a, b, c and d have a correlation less than 0.9. Now i want to check the correlation between a and b, a and c, and so on and kick those features out that correlate among eacht other. In the end, I then have only left for example a, c and d

Comment: I have edited my answer, hope it solves your problem.

Comment: Thank you very much. Unfortunatly, I only get set() as the output. Is there maybe a way to print the correlation matrix just for the features >0,9? Because for cormat I get know the correlation matrix with the rows as the features >0.9, but the columes contain all features